# Why my bigrams are still considering stopwords?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-cloud

The result still consider stopwords...
Few lines of my txt:

> Sensacional, uma das melhores remakes de animação sai do cinema emocionado, absurdamente lindo, insensibilidade de quem reclama do musical, lindo demais.
> (...)o filme depende muito da nostalgia da animação para funcionar. E apesar de ser eficaz, somente esse sentimento não sustenta o longa sozinho para dizer que esta obra tenha qualidade e refinamento cinematográficos.(...)A Bela e a Fera acerta em tornar a sua história ainda extremamente relevante nos dias atuais, e se de um lado inova o seu contexto social, por outro lado a falta de originalidade compromete que a obra seja mais impactante.

Reding txt

```
data <- read_tsv("bela.txt", locale = locale(encoding = "latin1"))
```

Making a corpus

```
datacorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(data))

datacorpus <- tm_map(datacorpus, PlainTextDocument)

datacorpus <- tm_map(datacorpus, removePunctuation) 

datacorpus <- tm_map(datacorpus, removeWords, stopwords('pt')) 

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(datacorpus,control=list(removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                                       stopwords = stopwords('pt'),
                                       removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                       tokenize = BigramTokenizer))

m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 10)

set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
      max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu67O.jpg

Comment: What is your question exactly? I'm not sure I clearly see a problem here.

Comment: I dont want bigram with stopwords like: a, o, os.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to drop bigrams that contain a stop word, using the [tidytext](http://tidytextmining.com/) package, you could do

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

set.seed(47)

data_frame(text = 'Sensacional, uma das melhores remakes de animação sai do cinema emocionado, absurdamente lindo, insensibilidade de quem reclama do musical, lindo demais. (...)o filme depende muito da nostalgia da animação para funcionar. E apesar de ser eficaz, somente esse sentimento não sustenta o longa sozinho para dizer que esta obra tenha qualidade e refinamento cinematográficos.(...)A Bela e a Fera acerta em tornar a sua história ainda extremamente relevante nos dias atuais, e se de um lado inova o seu contexto social, por outro lado a falta de originalidade compromete que a obra seja mais impactante.') %>% 
    unnest_tokens(bigram, text, 'ngrams', n = 2) %>%    # tokenize bigrams
    mutate(i = row_number()) %>%    # add index for later grouping
    unnest_tokens(word, bigram, drop = FALSE) %>%    # tokenize bigrams into words
    anti_join(data_frame(word = tm::stopwords('pt'))) %>%    # drop rows with stop words
    group_by(i) %>%    # group by bigram index
    filter(n() == 2) %>%    # drop bigram instances where only one word left
    summarise(bigram = unique(bigram)) %>%    # collapse groups to single bigram each
    count(bigram) %>% 
    { wordcloud::wordcloud(.$bigram, .$n, min.freq = 1, scale = c(1, .2), rot.per = .35, 
                           colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, 'Dark2')) }
```

[image]

Colors don't work here because there's a single occurrence of each, but should work fine at scale.

Comment: Is it possible remove stopword and make bigrams only with the remaining words?

Comment: Sure, it's simpler, actually; just tokenize to words first, `anti_join`, and then retokenize to bigrams. The problem is that you'll make bigrams of words that aren't actually next to each other when there was a stop word in between.

Comment: This is really hard for me... What am I doing wrong? - sorry I am new on R                                                                                                                                                                                                        

data_frame(text = datacorpus)

  unnest_tokens(unigram, text, 'ngrams', n = 1) 
  mutate(i = row_number()) 
  unnest_tokens(word, unigram, drop = FALSE)

Comment: anti_join(data_frame(word = tm::stopwords('pt')))
  
  unnest_tokens(bigram, text, 'ngrams', n = 2) 
  mutate(i = row_number()) 
  unnest_tokens(word, bigram, drop = FALSE)  
  
  group_by(i) 
  filter(n() == 2) 
  summarise(bigram = unique(bigram)) 
  count(bigram) % 
  { wordcloud::wordcloud(.$bigram, .$n, min.freq = 1, scale = c(1, .2), rot.per = .35, 
                         colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, 'Dark2')) }

Comment: You either need to use pipes, save intermediary variables, or nest the calls. It would look like `data_frame(text = ...) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
    anti_join(data_frame(word = tm::stopwords('pt'))) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(bigram, word, 'ngrams', n = 2) %>% 
    count(bigram) %>% 
    { wordcloud::wordcloud(.$bigram, .$n, ...) }` with the `...` filled in.